# Laying out a widget height in flutter relative to the height a Text widget would take

Tags: flutter, layout

I am trying to implement this UI:
[image]

The problem I am having is with the dashed line on the left, I can't think of a way to make it dynamically centered to the `CircleAvatar` while having its height be as tall as the text body would take without defining explicit sizes

Comment: check `IntrinsicHeight` widget

Comment: @pskink `IntrinsicHeight` won't work because dashed line implementations use `CustomPaints` or `LayoutBuilders` or calculate the dashes manually by setting an explicit height which I don't want to do

Comment: yes, it will work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679485/flutter-how-to-code-the-following-expansionpanel#64714941

Comment: @pskink I see, I thought CustomPaint wouldn't work since LayoutBuilder didn't. Can you explain why though?